# How to view photosphere image in image view

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am trying to develop a virtual tour android application. I have photosphere image in my local device. I need to open this image and allow the user to explore. But the image is not loading in the image view. Is there anyother way to load this image and take some actions on the image like scrolling or swiping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Photo Sphere Api's from Google play service. Below is example how to use it - 
And follow below link for more info -
[http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html][1]

```
// This listener will be called with information about the given panorama.
OnPanoramaInfoLoadedListener infoLoadedListener =
  new OnPanoramaInfoLoadedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPanoramaInfoLoaded(ConnectionResult result,
                                     Intent viewerIntent) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // If the intent is not null, the image can be shown as a
            // panorama.
            if (viewerIntent != null) {
                // Use the given intent to start the panorama viewer.
                startActivity(viewerIntent);
            }
        }
    }
 // If viewerIntent is null, the image is not a viewable panorama.
};
```

Create client instance and connect to it.
Once connected to the client, initiate the asynchronous check on whether
the image is a viewable panorama.
`client.loadPanoramaInfo(infoLoadedListener, panoramaUri)`;